# MySql Stored Procedure Loop Cursor - Syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Where is the syntax error?

```
DECLARE irid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tmp_joinid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE loopjoins_eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loopjoins_eof = TRUE;
START TRANSACTION;

    SET irid = (SELECT id FROM `tables` WHERE `adapter_id`=_aid AND `view_id`=_vid AND `name`=_tname);
    IF irid IS NOT NULL THEN

        DECLARE cur0 CURSOR FOR SELECT `joins`.`id` FROM `joins` WHERE `table_left_id`=irid OR `table_right_id`=irid;
        OPEN cur0;
            loopjoins: LOOP
                FETCH cur0 INTO tmp_joinid;
                IF loopjoins_eof THEN
                    LEAVE loopjoins;
                END IF;
                -- Lösche Join-Columns
                DELETE FROM `join_columns` WHERE `join_id`=tmp_joinid;
            END LOOP loopjoins;
        CLOSE cur0;

    END IF;
COMMIT;
SELECT irid;
```

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur0 CURSOR FOR SELECT `joins`.`id` FROM `joins` WHERE `table_left_id`=i' at line 12

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html):

> Cursor declarations must appear **before** handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.

Comment: But i need to select the 'id' for the cursor. How can i do that?

Comment: So? Read the sentence again. "...before handler declarations"

Comment: This one seems to work `DECLARE loopjoins_eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE tmp_joinid INT;
 DECLARE irid INT DEFAULT 0;

 DECLARE cur0 CURSOR FOR SELECT joins.id FROM joins WHERE table_left_id=irid OR table_right_id=irid;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loopjoins_eof = TRUE;
 
 START TRANSACTION;` But i need to select the irid at first. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I did, but why I still get the syntax error if I add `SET irid = (SELECT id FROM tables WHERE adapter_id=_aid AND view_id=_vid AND name=_tname);` after declare irid.

Answer (score 3):

a much better option is to avoid the cursor, you can replace the cursor with something like

```
DELETE FROM `join_columns`
WHERE `join_id` in 
  (SELECT `id` 
  FROM `joins` 
  WHERE `table_left_id`=irid OR `table_right_id`=irid);
```